# Updating an object within an array and it works, but a mysterious array gets added too

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an add to cart functionality on a personal project I'm making. The cart itself is an object with an array of products and a subtotal. It looks like this:

```js
let cart = {
  products: [
    { prodId: 1, quantity: 1, price: 6.99 },
    { prodId: 2, quantity: 2, price: 4.99 },
    { prodId: 3, quantity: 1, price: 15.99 },
  ],
  subTotal: 32.96,
};
```

I'm only interested in the products right now so I did
`products = cart.products` so that I'm just working with this:

```js
products = [
  { prodId: 1, quantity: 1, price: 6.99 },
  { prodId: 2, quantity: 2, price: 4.99 },
  { prodId: 3, quantity: 1, price: 15.99 }
];
```

I have logic to check to see if the product is already in the cart, so I'm working on adding to the quantity when the user clicks 'add to cart' on an item already in the cart. The logic for that looks like this:

```js
let productId = 3;

let oldProduct = products.filter(p => p.prodId === productId);
let index = products.indexOf(oldProduct);
if (index > -1) {
  products.slice(index, 1);
}
const updatedProduct = oldProduct.map(p => p.quantity++);
products.push(updatedProduct);
```

What I intend for this to do is:

1. get the existing product out of the array and bind it to `oldProduct`
2. remove the existing product out of the array completely using `slice`
3. update the existing product by adding 1 to the quantity using `map` and binding this to `updatedProduct`
4. pushing this updated product onto `products`

This works but an array gets added to `products` too. So the output in the console looks like this:

```js
[
  { prodId: 1, quantity: 1, price: 6.99 },
  { prodId: 2, quantity: 2, price: 4.99 },
  { prodId: 3, quantity: 2, price: 15.99 },
  [ 1 ]
]
```

I know that the array is the added quantity. I should probably mention that in the browser a new array gets added products every time you hit the button for a product that already exists in the cart, so if you clicked the button for the 3rd item 5 times, the products array would look like this:

```js
[
  { prodId: 1, quantity: 1, price: 6.99 },
  { prodId: 2, quantity: 2, price: 4.99 },
  { prodId: 3, quantity: 6, price: 15.99 },
  [ 1 ],
  [ 2 ],
  [ 3 ],
  [ 4 ],
  [ 5 ]
]
```

I think it's something to do with `updatedProduct` because when I logged it, it was just the array, but if it's just the array, then the quantity wouldn't go up, so I'm really confused. Also, when I check `typeOf` of `updatedProduct` it says it's an object, so I really have no idea what's happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `oldProduct.map(p => p.quantity++);` returns an array containing the new value of `p.quantity`

Comment: [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) takes two arguments, "_from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array_". Does `products.slice(index, 1);` do what you're intending?

Comment: I believe you want to be using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're way overthinking it, and you're also using `filter` when you meant `find`, and `slice` when you meant `splice`.  No worries though. I think you want something like this:

```js
let cart = {
  products: [
    { prodId: 1, quantity: 1, price: 6.99 },
    { prodId: 2, quantity: 2, price: 4.99 },
    { prodId: 3, quantity: 1, price: 15.99 },
  ],
  subTotal: 32.96,
};
let productId = 3;
cart.products.map(p => {
  if (p.prodId === productId) {
    p.quantity++;
    cart.subTotal += p.price;
  }
});
console.log(cart)
```

Basically, if I'm understanding, you just want to increment the quantity of a product with a given ID. <strike>All you really need to do is map a function to each product which just does 2 things: checks if the ID is matched, and increments the quantity if so. This is a great use case for short circuit conditionals. It allows you to do all that w/ just the one line. Very clean.</strike>

I edited it further and expanded that function to also add the product's price to the subtotal. Not as simple, but maybe what you need/want?

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

```
oldProduct.map(p => p.quantity++);
```

returns an array containing the new quantity, which you then push into your `products` array.

You want to get the object with the updated quantity and push that.

Also,

- instead of using `.filter` and then `.indexOf`, you can use [.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- I believe, given what you're trying to do, you're looking for [.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and not [.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```js
let products = [
  { prodId: 1, quantity: 1, price: 6.99 },
  { prodId: 2, quantity: 2, price: 4.99 },
  { prodId: 3, quantity: 1, price: 15.99 }
];

let productId = 3;

let index = products.findIndex(p => p.prodId === productId); // findIndex
if (index > -1) {
  let oldProduct = products[index]
  products.splice(index, 1); // .splice
  oldProduct.quantity++;
  products.push(oldProduct); // push the object
}


console.log(products);
```